# Quadratic Equation Visual Basic 2010+

Tags: visual-studio-2010, equation, quadratic, msgbox

I have to write a program which calculate quadratic equation and find its roots. The roots *must* be displayed via MsgBox-es, and the variables A, B and C *must* be entered via InputBox-es. For now I have written this, but it somehow doesn't work and I can't figure out why. 
**I'm new to Visual Basic ..

```
Public Class Form1
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As Integer
Dim Det As Double
Dim x1 As Double
Dim x2 As Double


Private Sub txtA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtA.Click
    txtA.Text = InputBox("Please, enter value of the variable A.", "Enter A")
End Sub

Private Sub txtB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtB.Click
    txtB.Text = InputBox("Please, enter value of the variable B.", "Enter B")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCalculate.Click
    A = Val(txtA.Text)
    B = Val(txtB.Text)
    C = Val(txtC.Text)
    Det = B ^ 2 + 4 * A * C
    If Det > 0 Then
        x1 = (-B + Math.Sqrt(Det)) / (2 * A)
        x2 = (-B - Math.Sqrt(Det)) / (2 * A)
        MsgBox("The roots are " + x1 + " and " + x2 + " ! ", 64, "2 Roots")
    ElseIf Det = 0 Then
        x1 = -B / (2 * A)
        MsgBox("The roots are " + x1 + " ! ", 64, "1 Double Root")
    ElseIf Det < 0 Then
        MsgBox("No roots ! ", 64, "No Roots")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtC.Click
    txtC.Text = InputBox("Please, enter value of the variable C.", "Enter C")
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdClear.Click
    txtA.Text = ""
    txtB.Text = ""
    txtC.Text = ""
End Sub
```

End Class

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg690.jpg <-- Screen view

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problem was just because the x1 and x2 must be in Str()..

```
If Det > 0 Then
        x1 = (-B + Math.Sqrt(Det)) / (2 * A)
        x2 = (-B - Math.Sqrt(Det)) / (2 * A)
        MsgBox("The roots are " + Str(x1) + " and " + Str(x2) + " ! ", 64, "2 Roots")
    ElseIf Det = 0 Then
        x = -B / (2 * A)
        MsgBox("The roots are " + Str(x) + " ! ", 64, "1 Double Root")
```